# Jasmine ajax stub

Tags: jquery, ajax, jasmine

I have a jasmine ajax stub in my before each block that looks like this

```
jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest('testpage.html').andReturn(
  {
    responseText: JSON.stringify(window.__html__['src/sign-up/testpage.html'])
  }
);
```

My understanding is that whenever a request is now made to testpage.html it will return the response object in a synchronous manner. However this doesn't seem to be the way it's functioning the response is returned async. In Jasmine 2 how would I catch any requests to a url and return data synchronously?